# Don't take everything at face value

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, wordplay

> M. Night Shyamalan's claim to fame.
>   A rapid switch of these  may prove catastrophic.
>   You can do this at home, at the gym, and now even on a bus.
>   The Notebook, Clueless, and Twilight are some examples of this.
>   I consist of each of these things and at my core one more

What am I?

Hint:

> If I were to remove two lines from the first four lines the answer would be the same but different

---

Riddle changes since first posting:

- Added the word rapid to the second line
- Changed "all" to "each of" in the last line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Slightly not-serious guess:

You are:

> [Bop It!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bop_It) More specifically, the Bop It Extreme version

M. Night Shyamalan's claim to fame.

> M. Night Shyamalan's is famous for movies which have big **twists**

A rapid switch of these may prove catastrophic.

> This refers to the poles switching. Poles --> **Pull**

You can do this at home, at the gym, and now even on a bus.

> You can do a **spin** class at the gym, at home and [now even on a bus!](http://www.bostonmagazine.com/health/blog/2015/05/28/bike-bus-boston/)

The Notebook, Clueless, and Twilight are some examples of this.

> These are examples of movies that would be described as chick **flicks**

I consist of all these things and at my core one more

> Twist, Spin, Flick, Switch are all possibilities on a Bop It Extreme device as well as the big **Bop It** button in the middle/core

Regarding the hint

> If you remove the lines about the **flick** and the **spin**, you end up with the original Bop It, which just had **twist**, **pull** and **bop**

Comment: Yup! You got it. Though the answer is slightly more specific, your explanation is spot on for each clue minus the one you missed

Comment: Oh wow, that was the first thing that popped into my head just from the 2 movie clues, didn't think it'd actually be correct. Is the 'more specific' answer a certain variety? Hence the hint of removing 2 lines and still being slightly same answer?

Comment: Yeah it is a certain variety which is what the hint is hinting at

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Ah ok, I thought it was a 'pull' handle, but there were a few sources saying the green was a toggle switch which fit easier.

Comment: I removed my previous comment about the second clues and put it in your answer instead, I hope that is okay

Answer (score 2):

You might be:

> **Motion**

M. Night Shyamalan's claim to fame.

> Motion Pictures

A rapid switch of these may prove catastrophic.

> Rapid change in movement/ motion may cause accidents/ muscle cramps

You can do this at home, at the gym, and now even on a bus.

> Well! You can move at you home, the gym and even on the bus.

The Notebook, Clueless, and Twilight are some examples of this.

> All three are motion pictures.

I consist of all these things and at my core one more

> I am not sure about this one.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the correct answer. You are somewhat on the right track for lines 1 and 4 though. I'm going to make a slight change to line 5 which shouldn't effect your answer but should make the riddle a bit clearer, and also add a hint